# Can't add directory to path on Windows 10

Tags: python, path, windows-10, environment-variables

I don't know if Stackoverflow is the right place for my question but I don't know where else to ask. So feel free to move my question to another community.

So I have added the path to "pip.exe" (which is in the "Scripts" directory) to my Environment variables by pressing "win key + pause" => "Advanced system settings" => "Environment variables..." => "New..."

Then I closed all cmd's and rebooted my machine and then opened a cmd windows again, typed "echo %path% but the path which I have added wasn't there.

Any ideas?

Comment: Don't should just add that to your existing `PATH` environment variable instead of adding a new one?

Comment: did you add in system variables or user variables ? Also there should be one path variable by default. You need to append pip.exe path to the existing

Comment: Omg... My mistake was that I have added a new environment variable. But all paths should be in the Path variable. Never needed to do this in Windows before. Thanks! All clear now. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open up the variable named "PATH" you should be able to add the pip path to it. The paths are stored in this variable and separated by a semi-colon.

Something like;

```
...;C:/Python34;C:/Python34/Scripts
```

Answer (score -1):

There is an easy solution to this problem : add the it through the command line

open the command line ( you can tap "cmd" in the windows search bar to find it)

once you are in the command line, Type :

```
SETX PATH "here put the path of the folder you want to add to path"
```

/!\ if the command is not immediatly available after that, you need to close the commande line first and reopen it, for the change to be taken into account

Comment: This replaces your path, probably breaking many programs on your system. If you want to ADD to path, you have to use `setx PATH "%PATH%;<your-new-path>"`